# When/how are tag badges created or available to track

Tags: discussion, support, tag-badges

The [actions-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actions-builder) tag was created roughly two weeks ago. Since that time, it has gotten a small smattering of questions and answers, some of which have been accepted.

[image: Top users of actions-builder]

I would like to track my progress for this for my next tag badge, but selecting the gear icon to choose this...

[image: Next tag badge gear icon]

and filtering with "actions" doesn't show the badge as an option to pick.

[image: Tag badge picker, filtering on "actions"]

Does there need to be more activity for a tag badge to be available? If so, what is this level (or where is it documented)?

Comment: I have created this tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-mask since more that two weeks (probably months from now) and It's not showing too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags) that tags require 100 questions before badges can be awarded for them.

> If enough votes are earned in a tag with 100+ total questions, the badge will be automatically created and awarded.

To prevent confusion (since you aren't going to get a badge), you can't track such tags either.